# JointJS: Add a label on the validateConnection Event?

Tags: jointjs

I have a `validateConnection` event within which I have a lot of conditions. Now on one of these conditions, I want to add a custom label to the link that gets created. How do I do this within `validateConnection`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

prepare a 'placeholder' for the future label - it creates a label without text:

```
new joint.dia.Link({
    labels: [
       { position: 0.5 }
    ]
}),
```

Then in the `validateConnection` set the label text value throught the `attr`

```
validateConnection: function(cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView) {
        if (cellViewT) {
            linkView.model.prop('labels/0/attrs/text/text', cellViewT.model.attr('text/text'));
        } else {
            linkView.model.prop('labels/0/attrs/text/text', '')
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/hxbfo0m4/

Answer (score 0):

```
joint.dia.Link({
             labels: [
                { position: 0.5, attrs: { text: { text: 'test' } } }
            ]
```

Comment: Please explain this code, and also format it properly.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.